# Sitting position for 61 key piano

Tags: piano, posture

I was wondering if there is any specific guidance for sitting position for piano in terms of positioning your hands, left on bass keys and right on trible keys. I guess on a grand piano it will be centre where bass and trible scales might have split equally. In my Casio ctk-5000 there are two bass scales and 3 trible scales. I am sitting in the centre but its very uncomfortable  playing first trible scales. Do I just keep practice till I get use to it or there any guidelines? Please excuse my noob terminology  and ask me if anything doesn't made sense to you

Answer (score 1):

Whatever keyboard you play, you will move slightly to left or right when you play. There is no standard position, only the place where are comfortable. When playing higher or lower notes mainly, you'll move right or left accordingly. Yes, you'll be basically in front of middle C, but please don't get out the ruler...

Actually, 88, 76 and 61 are the industry standards, so 71 is a little odd.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected title. Its 61 keys

Answer (score 1):

I always heard "generally center yourself at the middle of middle D".  And then lean/scoot depending on the song.

So you could try that, but, you know, there's no valid REASON to center yourself there.